# How does formaldehyde cause protein-DNA crosslinking?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, protein-binding

How does formaldehyde cause protein-DNA crosslinking?  I would guess it's because the strongly polar water molecule interacts strongly with polar residues on a protein-DNA complex, and adding a less polar solvent causes the DNA and protein to pull more tightly on each other than their pull on the solvent, but I haven't been able to find an answer online.

Comment: aldehydes actually react with amines in protein and DNA to covalently attach the protein to the DNA in such experiments.  check out slides 3+ http://synapses.clm.utexas.edu/lab/howto/cross-linking%20fixatives.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2866014/

In this work they find that formaldehyde crosslinking happens by formation of a methylol adduct (due to nucleophilic attack by N or S in case of proteins) in protein which then attacks the DNA or vice-versa.
The final crosslink is by a methylene bridge

Formaldehyde can react to amino groups in nucleotides and proteins and form a schiff's base, but i dont have a clue how this is involved in crosslinking